# Performance FireBird

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Estou tentando deixar o FireBird mais rápido para inserir registros via Procedure, porém não estou conseguindo, atualmente vejo que o FireBird não utiliza 100% dos recursos disponíveis da máquina, procurei já em vários lugares e realizei algumas alterações no arquivo `Firebird.conf`, são as seguintes:

```
DefaultDbCachePages = 16384
FileSystemCacheThreshold = 268435456
FileSystemCacheSize = 80
CpuAffinityMask = 15
```

Mas não obtive melhoras na performance do firebird.
Tenho de configuração em minha máquina:
Intel Core I5 2400.
8GB RAM
HD 1 TB.

Estas procedures copiam os registros de tabelas que são importadas via arquivo csv, e inserem nas tabelas que o sistema grava os registros.
Alguém sabe como realizar este Tunning de performance para este tipo de procedimento?

Comment: O melhor site para você encontrar informações sobre tunning de firebird é na Firebase. Veja este artigo: https://firebase.com.br/artigo.php?id=3098

Comment: Não existe uma configuração padrão para qualquer ambiente em que o Firebird está rodando. Você deve encontrar a melhor configuração para negócio x servidor x versão Firebird. Por isso que é complicado uma resposta exata a sua pergunta.